# Continued fractions in f# using seq

Tags: algorithm, list, f#, functional-programming, sequence

Hi is there a way to solve continued fractions in f# using seq , not list?

```
let cfToScalar cf = List.foldBack (fun elem acc -> float elem + (1.0 / float acc)) cf System.Double.MaxValue
```

Someting like that but i want to use seq instead of lists

Comment: Just change List.foldback to Seq.foldBack

Comment: Don't expect having "infinite seq" this way though ; `foldBack` requires to fully traverse the container first (the current [implementation](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1227) convert the sequence in array internally)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, you can just change `List.foldback` to `Seq.foldback` and your function will now accept sequences. Also note as Sehnsucht said, `foldback`'s current implementation requires a conversion to an array so an input that is an infinite sequence will not work.

On a side note, since [F# 4.0's normalization of the collection modules](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ListSeqArrayAdditions.md) swapping out one module for another in general now possible with most functions in the List/Array/Seq modules.